# why pip install do not download the depended package which be defind in setup.py?

Tags: python, setuptools, install-requires

my python project is packaged by setuptools,this is my setup.opt:

```
[metadata]
name = totems_pycommon
version = 1.0.0
#long_description = file: README.rst, CHANGELOG.rst, LICENSE.rst
include_package_data = True

# 依赖
install_requires=
    kafka==1.2.0
    elasticsearch7==7.14.1
    requests

[options]
python_requires = >=3.6
packages = find:
package_dir =
    =.

[options.packages.find]
where = .
#include = *
exclude = *.test

[options.package_data]
* = *.ini
```

i defind the depend package in **install_requires**,and i thought when i package my project by setuptools and then install the package by pip install,the depend package will be download automatically ,but it did not ,why and what the **install_requires** is used for?

[image: when i install my project]

Answer (score 0):

You should change `kafka==1.2.0` for `kafka-python==1.2.0`

```
install_requires=
    kafka-python==1.2.0
    elasticsearch7==7.14.1
    requests
```

Answer (score 0):

refer to this topic https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html#options

you have to move `install_requires` and `include_package_data` to `options` section

your `setup.cfg` should be:

```
[metadata]
name = totems_pycommon
version = 1.0.0
#long_description = file: README.rst, CHANGELOG.rst, LICENSE.rst

[options]
python_requires = >=3.6
packages = find:
package_dir =
    =.

include_package_data = True
# 依赖
install_requires=
    kafka==1.2.0
    elasticsearch7==7.14.1
    requests

[options.packages.find]
where = .
#include = *
exclude = *.test

[options.package_data]
* = *.ini
```